# How to connect two wildly different power sources?

Tags: batteries, generator

I want to be able to have a kinetic generator and a mains plug both plugged into a battery, so that I can choose to pedal or rely on the mains to charge when I wish without needing to remember to unplug one for the other.

Initially I tried connecting them in parallel but this was obviously stupid and the backfeed caused the kinetic generator's main board to catch fire. The mains plug outputs 24V 3.5A DC, and the kinetic generator outputs 14V 3A DC.

I thought maybe cutting some wires and soldering in a diode for each source would suffice, but after some searching it looks like this doesn't really work. I'm not really sure where to go from here, I presume it'll be something to do with MOSFETs. Ideally I'd just buy something off the shelf that I could just plug them into but I'm not really even sure what to search for.

Comment: What are you trying to power? What is its voltage requirement? What is its current requirement? Why MOSFETs?

Comment: What do you want to use as your criterion for which source to use?

Comment: @Transistor I would like to charge a Jackery 1000. I assumed MOSFETs because that's how people seem to do stuff like this efficiently, my electrical engineering knowledge is very rudimentary

Comment: What’s a kinetic generator? What’s your end goal.

Comment: @Hearth When I pedal I would like to stop the mains from charging the battery

Comment: @winny Another name for a pedal power generator

Comment: @0x777C You could use the diodes, but also add a relay to disconnect the mains power when the kinetic generator is making power. Although I don't really understand how this system will work well, because the mains will keep the battery full 100% of the time, so when you pedal, the battery is already full from the mains.

Comment: I've seen rather simplistic non-electronic solutions for this. The pedal generator (which looked like an exercise bike) had a switch mounted under the seat. When someone sat on the bike, it pressed the switch and switched between wall power and bike power via a relay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you’re proposing needs a couple of things:

- a power path controller to select one source or the other
- A boost converter to normalize the kinetic output to 24V

Guess what? Does your Jackery have a solar input? Perhaps more than one? If so, it's got you covered. You can drive that solar input with your kinetic generator in place of a solar panel, and the Jackery will manage the voltage/current details. No diodes needed.

MORE: You mentioned that your unit is a Jackery 1000. This has the 'ANDERSON' input, which accepts a 'Solar Saga' Y cable for 2 solar panels. This Y cable is a diode setup so that the panels don't interact. You could use this with your mechanical generator together with a panel.

Comment: It does in fact! That's a really smart idea!

Answer (score 14):

There are some single-chip solutions for this exact situation, called OR-ing controllers.

While most of them are designed for use at low voltages (e.g. the TPS211xA, limited to 5.5 V) there are some that can work at higher voltages, and ones that use external switches that can be coerced into working at arbitrarily high voltages. The [LTC4416](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/4416fa.pdf) would work perfectly, for instance, with a handful of additional parts. By driving its E1 and E2 pins with appropriate signals derived from your pedal generator, you can get it to disconnect the wall adapter and connect the pedal generator whenever it's producing high enough voltages (where you can set what counts as high enough).

The implementation would be something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXKNkU.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This is simply taken directly from the LTC4416's datasheet example schematic (It's my day off, I can't be bothered to do any actual design work! But really, if a datasheet example can just work out of the box, it's usually a good idea to go with that.), and will connect your pedal generator to the output whenever it produces at least 10.8 V. It has some hysteresis, so the pedal generator will stay connected to the output until it falls below 9.0 V. The wall power supply is connected whenever the pedal generator is not. If you want to change those threshold voltages, you can change R1, R2, and R3 according to the equations in the datasheet (the "V1 is less than V2" case, equations on the left side of page 9).

You are free to use any other MOSFET you like, as long as it meets the requirements for power handling. As this should only switch infrequently, you shouldn't need to worry about any heatsinking as long as the on resistance is low enough. The LTC4416 clamps the gate voltage to a maximum of 9.1 volts below the rail, so there are no concerns about having to find high-gate-voltage PFETs. (A previous version of this answer went out of the way to use the high-voltage Si7315, when it turns out a cheaper FET would actually work fine.)

The datasheet's recommended SUP75P03-07 is obsolete and overkill for this application besides, so I've used the cheap and readily available Si2369 in my schematic. If you must use a through-hole part, the IRF9Z24N should work.

You may need to add a capacitor (probably ceramic, around 100 nF to 10 μF) between V1 and ground. V2 *probably* doesn't need one, but an identical capacitor there wouldn't hurt anything.

Answer (score 2):

You have one of these portable power pack things, not a simple battery, so it doesn't matter what the input voltage is (otherwise you'd have to convert the voltage to match the battery voltage). Your goal is to disconnect the mains when you are pedalling your bike generator.

You can use a diode in series with each power source, and connect the cathodes (outputs) of the diodes together, but the highest voltage will always "win", and that's the mains.

To solve this, you can use a suitable relay to change the power source when the 14V is on:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNgt8y.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Compared to Hearth's answer with an integrated circuit, this one is possibly less reliable in the long term since the relay is a mechanical part, but also simpler to build especially if you are a beginner.

The type of relay can be a common "automotive changeover relay".

Another obvious possibility is to add a switch, instead of a relay, that you can change to pedal input when you start pedalling and back to mains input when you are done.

Comment: If you're going to the trouble of using a relay, with changeover contacts, why bother with the diodes? Just connect the 14V input to the NO contact as well as the coil, then you don't need D1 and D2 to avoid backfeeding PSUs.  And use automotive relays.  They're nominally 12V but specced to work higher, and usually have a built-in flyback diode.  Otherwise, add a flyback diode to this circuit to protect the 14V PSU output stage

Comment: @ChrisH thanks, answer has been edited

Comment: This could have a problem with the highly variable secondary supply (it's a pedal generator; those will output voltages proportional to the speed you're pedalling); a 12 V coil won't switch on at the low end, and a 5 V one would be destroyed at the high end.

Answer (score 0):

Depends what you mean by "work".

This is not a battery, it is a consumer product that contains a battery and one hopes has appropriate charging and protection circuits to protect the battery from mishandling.  You need to provide the type of power stated in the labeling and instructions.

Now if it has a general DC input that can accept a wide variety of voltages, then okay.  In that case yes, you can simply merge several DC supplies using diodes.   This will have a characteristic I would call "overrunning" where the highest voltage supply will block any other power supply who cannot create that much voltage. For instance, if you have a 24V DC mains supply diode-paralleled with a solar panel that outputs 19V max possible, the solar will be nudged out entirely and won't provide a single watt. Likewise if your exercise machine had a max voltage below 24V it would simply freewheel for lack of load.

Whereas if you had a solar panel with 29V open circuit voltage, and 24V was in the middle of its working range, the solar panel will provide slightly over 24V, and that may not be at its maximum power point.

Some sources will increase until current flows.  If your exercise machine is capable of stepping up its voltage above 24V, it will end up *co-charging* the Jackery alongside the AC mains - that is, it will productively use all the power you make as well as all the power your mains DC supply can provide.

It sounds like your exercise machine is not capable of exceeding 24V, so it would not charge the Jackery unless the mains source AC is interrupted.  But that is fine. Why labor? Mains can do it for pennies.  User235731 has the ticket there - a simple relay that knocks out the mains when pedaling.  I don't see any call for semiconductors.

That said, I do endorse the diodes in addition to the relay. Cheap circuit protection.

Comment: "Why labor? Mains can do it for pennies." So I can charge my laptop & phone if hyperinflation happens, and also to give myself a practical reason to do cardio.